# Sonarqube results once confirmed in one branch dont carry forward to other branch of the same code, they are again set Open by default?

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

Im able to currently run Bamboo to auto-branch and run scans against all newly created branches. Now if i change the state of one of the vulnerabilities say by clicking "Confirm", it doesn't get carry forwarded to the other branches of the same code. Is there any way to accomplish this?
So now even if take time to review the issues from the analysis result, if anyone creates a branch out of the same code, it again report the vulnerabilities afresh as Open.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want in current versions of SonarQube.

Comment: I used the apis available to get the list of issues for a project in which I already reviewed all the reported issues in the scan, and then compare the json output with a list of issues of another branch of the same code. Then if i see if its the same issue on the same line of the same code, i then make a list of the issue ids which needs to be set to false positive or confirmed accordingly. Then i use the bulk change api to set the resolution or status accordingly.
Only caveat is that if the code changes in the file changes the line number, we cannot carry forward those cases! Your thoughts